# Cómo generar código autoincrementable con las iniciales de una categoría en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

tengo mi tabla producto conformada de la siguiente manera:

```
create table producto(
    codigo varchar(15) not null,
    categoria varchar(100) not null,
    primerasLetras varchar(3) not null,
    primary key(codigo)
);
```

En donde "primerasLetras" guardo las 3 primeras letras de mi categoria, ejemplo: FILTRO DE GASOLINA = FIL, TORNILLO = TOR ...

Posterior a esto e creado un disparador que me ayuda a genear los codigos

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER generar_codigos BEFORE INSERT ON producto FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE siguiente_codigo int;
    SET siguiente_codigo = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(codigo, 4), SIGNED INTEGER)), 0) FROM producto) + 1;
    SET NEW.codigo = CONCAT(NEW.primerasLetras, LPAD(siguiente_codigo, 3, '0'));
END $
```

Al realizar un insert a mi tabla los codigos quedan de la siguiente manera:

- FIL001
- FIL002
- ACE003
- TOR004
- FIL005

Lo que quisiera realizar es que al cambiar las primeras 3 letras el 001 se reinicie de tal forma que queden de la siguiente manera:

- FIL001
- FIL002
- ACE001
- TOR001
- FIL003

Comment: Si bien tu planteamiento es medianamente claro, no se ve lo que has hecho para conseguirlo. Parece más bien que nos estes asignando una tarea, lo siento. Aqui no realizamos tareas, miramos de solucionar problemas concretos con errores concretos, y en tu caso no veo ninguno porque no has intentado nada. Debes procurar poner un [example]. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y cómo realizar preguntas que sean bien aceptadas por la comunidad, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, compuse mi pregunta y añadí lo que e conseguido hacer hasta ahorita para ser mas claro.

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que la tabla producto tiene tres columnas, de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `producto` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Puedes plantear, el siguiente código:

```
$producto = 'FILTRO DE ACEITE';
$pdo = new PDO(...);

try {

    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $sql_ref_max = "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM productos";
    $smt_max = $pdo->query($sql_ref_max);
    $max = intval($smt_max->fetch())
    $ref_str = subtr($producto, 0,3);
    $ref_producto = $ref_str . str_pad($max, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO productos (id, ref, producto) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $smt_insert = $pdo->prepare($sql_insert);
    $smt_insert->execute(array($max, $ref_producto, $producto));
    $pdo->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
}
```

Donde primero obtienes el número de id a utilizar para el siguiente producto, y construyes la referencia con [la tres primeras letras](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) del producto y el identificador obtenido con el select, utilizando la función [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php). Utilizo la [clase PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php) para trabajar con la BBDD y una transacción.